# Remove all words starting with "http" in a string?

Tags: java, string, replace

I simply want to replace all words starting with "http" and ends with space or "\n" in a string

Example string is.

Full results below;

http://www.google.com/abc.jpg is a url of an image.

or some time it comes like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xwhatever this is an example text

Result of the string should be like

is a url of an image.

or some time it comes like  this is an example text

I simply want to replace it with ""; i know the logic but don't know the function.

My logic is

```
string.startwith("http","\n")// starts with http and ends on next line or space

.replaceAll("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "https://www.google.com/abc.jpg is a url of an image.";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("https?://.*?\\s+", ""));

}
```

O/P :

```
is a url of an image.
```

Comment: or if it starts with https i have to call it again with https or there is another approach

Comment: @Nepster - fixed it.. :). Now it workds for both `http` and `https`

Comment: I am asking to make a single function to do both http and https in a single string. Your Previous Answer works fine when i call it twice once with http and second time with https . Now i am asking is there a way to create a single function ,+10 for the answer

Comment: And please can you explain me .*? meaning and i think s is any number of words

Comment: @Nepster - I had put the `?` in the wrong place. Check the latest edit .. BTW `https?` matches both `http` and `https` i.e, it matches `http` followed by 0 or 1 `s`. `.*?` is a reluctant quantifier which matches one character at a time from beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57551/discussion-between-nepster-and-thelostmind).

Answer (score 1):

`String.replaceAll()` allows you to use a regex. In a regex, `^` allows you to capture the beginning of the String. Hence, you can do like that :

```
System.out.print("http://google-http".replaceAll("^http", ""));
```

result:

```
://google-http
```

The `http` at the beginning has be removed but not the one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "https://www.google.com/abc.jpg is a url of an image.";
    String subStr1 = "http://";
    String substr2 = "https://";
    String foundStr = "";
    if(str.startsWith(subStr1)) {
        foundStr = subStr1;
    } 
    if (str.startsWith(subStr2)) {
        foundStr = subStr2;
    }
        str = str.replaceAll(foundStr, "");
        str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

Comment: it will only replace http . I want to remove full path @TheLostMind answer is right . but i have to call it twice once by http and second time with https

Comment: This code will execute correctly, if you need to simplify this code, you can create an array with elements "http://" and "https://" then  using array search function , you can check a substring is present in given string. if found replace that string with empty character.

Comment: you are not getting me. My question is to replace the full word which may not at the start . see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm . My http url may be in the middle of a string.but your code search whether it starts with.